# Search automation in delphi?

Tags: delphi, chromium, google-search, twebbrowser, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to automate search.

I am using google.com for search the search button name is btnk.

I googled and found below code of clicking button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
x: integer;  
thelink: OleVariant;  
begin  
thelink:= WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('A');  
if thelink.Length > 0 then  
  begin  
  for x := 0 to thelink.Length-1 do  
    begin  
    if Pos('btnK', thelink.Item(x).id) > 0 then
      begin  
        thelink.Item(x).click;  
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

but the code didn't finds 'btnK' or clicks on that.

for now i am manually entering the search text

Comment: Why are you automating a GUI control? Why don't you just post the request?

Comment: Nonsense. If a browswer can retrieve it, you can get it yourself. You just have to set the proper User-Agent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sir can you please show me an example with google.com ?

Comment: *"but the code didn't finds 'btnK' or clicks on that.*" - Please be more specific in describing the symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

Google provides various api's for programmers to use at no cost for trying and reasonable cost for long term and extensive use. The following might be against the google terms of use, and provided here just for academic discussion ;) Also, this kind of solutions are  usually short lived since they are vulnerable to minor editions of the content they rely on.

This might become tricky as `www.google.com` seems to respond with different pages depending on which browser is calling. I don't have `chromium` installed and can not check what response it gets but `TWebBrowser` (IE 11) gets something close to what you seem to expect.

Look at the source (`View source` in r-click popup menu of `TWebBrowser`, `View page source` in r-click popup menu of `Chrome` ...) to verify element types and field names.

Following is based on the response `TWebBrowser` gets, as it answers your question.

You are searching a page `https://www.google.com` for a `html` tag `A` with a field `id` whos value is `btnK`. But such a thing doesn't exist! Not in the page that `TWebBrowser` receives.

You are obviously looking for this one:

```
<input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit">
```

As you see, it's an `input` tag with a `name` field whos value is `btnK`

So, modify your code so that the first line becomes

```
  thelink:= WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('input');
```

and the sixth line becomes

```
    if Pos('btnK', thelink.Item(x).name) > 0 then
```

and indeed, it activates a search when you call `click` on it.

---

But you can do it simpler. Look at the URL after you entered something (say, 'Delphi') in the search field of `https://www.google.com`. For me it looks as follows:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi&rlz=1C1Y...
```

The part `'q=delphi'` is the interesting one (it might not be immediately after the question mark but further in the URL).

So, you can simply have an edit box to enter the word to search for and a webbrowser to show the result

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  search = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(search + Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. i tried this but there is no result shown. this ain't working for me. not the api one but the other ole version of your answer

Comment: @John You need to be specific about what *...ain't working for me.* So, what exactly did you try with?